Problem with pip install (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt')
I wanted to use contributions graph in my Django project, so after quick research I decided to use 'contributions-django' library. But when I tried to install it, I got stuck with this error::

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'requirements.txt'
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit
code: 1 ╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip.

I am no pip expert, but I can see that requirements.txt file exists in this repository (altough it's empty). How to fix this? Can I install the libary manually? How? Thanks for help in advance.
At the comment request, here is the command I used:
first I activated virtual environment:
my_venv\Scripts\activate

then I used this command to install the library:
pip install contributions-django


Show us the exact command you used.

I edited the post, used command is now included

See https://github.com/vsoch/contributions-django/issues/3 . The bug was reported in 2020, still open. The last commit also was 4 years ago. The project seems to be abandoned.
This command works, though:
pip install git+https://github.com/vsoch/contributions-django.git

You need Git installed and git command present in the %PATH%.

It worked, thanks a lot! Although I already have another problem with this library, please take a look if you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78301090/html-template-from-contributions-django-libraty-not-rendering-properly

@Ravdar No idea how the module works, sorry!

Search for Python IDLE in the windows search bar and select 'open file location'.
In the folder that will open, select IDLE again, and with a right click, from the options that will open, select "open file location" again.
Then select the "scripts" folder
To install a library, we need the address of the script folder.
Move the mouse to the address area and by right-clicking and dragging the mouse, the entire address is selected (turns blue). With ctrl + C (or right click, copy) we copy the address.
We go to the windows search area, write "cmd" to open the windows command line. Click "open"
In the black window we write "cd" and with ctrl + V (or right mouse click), we paste the address we copied earlier.
We are now in the Scripts folder. We write "pip install +(library)" and press enter. So after a while the library you selected will be installed.

OP has no issue running pip itself (they'd get "pip is not recognized as an internal or external command" etc.), and this is not very good advice in general - you should set your Python Scripts directory to be in PATH, or just use python -m pip (in pip's specific case) instead of having to cd to the Scripts directory.
