Html template from contributions-django libraty not rendering properly
I want to use a GitHub-like contributions calendar in my Django project. After a quick research, I found the contributions_django library. After some problems, I managed to install it, but even after following the instructions, the contributions graph does not load properly on the page. What should be an empty contributions graph looks like this:

First I imported the library to my views.py file:
from contributions_django.graphs import generate_contributors_graph

Then I used 'generate_contributions_graph' method in my view:
contributions = []
calendar = generate_contributors_graph(contributions, title="Decks reviews")
return render(request, "myapp/user_stats.html", {"calendar":calendar}

Finally, I placed this line of code in the "user_stats" HTML template:
{% include "contributions_django/graph.html" %}

And that's it. It should display an empty graph, but it doesn't. I also tried to insert some dates in the "calendar", but it didn't work; nothing changed:
today = timezone.now()
last_week = today - timedelta(days=7)
contributions = [last_week, today]
calendar = generate_contributors_graph(contributions, title="Decks reviews")

If you have any idea what the cause of the problem might be, please help. Thanks in advance.

I actually haven't used this package, but some quick question pops into my mind:
Have you correctly registered this package in installed apps list in settings.py? Have you checked whether the calendar variable has the proper value or is of expected type? Lastly, are there any errors in client-side? Press F12 and check the console. You might want to attach these to your question
